# Display joined data with Peewee ORM

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee

Using PeeWee Orm I have created two tables (I've removed a lot of the fields that are irrelevant to this query)

#### Product Table

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    fm_price = FloatField(null=True)
    magento = IntegerField(db_column='magento_id', null=True, index=True)
    sku = CharField(index=True, null=True, unique=True)
    # Compare these two fields to on or offline products
    magento_status_fm = IntegerField(null=True)
    magento_status_ff = IntegerField(null=True)
    # Date fields to put error dates in
    ff_price_error = DateField(index=True, null=True)
    ff_stock_error = DateField(index=True, null=True)
    fm_price_error = DateField(index=True, null=True)
    fm_stock_error = DateField(index=True, null=True)
    ff_check_date = DateField(null=True, index=True)  # When did we get this product from FF

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        indexes = (
            (('fm_price', 'vip_price', 'education_price'), False),
        )
```

#### Prices Table

```
class Price(BaseModel):
    price_pk = PrimaryKeyField()
    entity_id = ForeignKeyField(Product, to_field='magento', null=True, on_update='CASCADE', on_delete='CASCADE')
    customer_group_id = IntegerField(null=True)
    final_price = FloatField(null=True)
    min_price = FloatField(null=True)
    check_date = DateField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = (
            (('entity_id', 'customer_group_id'), True),
        )
```

Example Content:

Products:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | CREATION            | MODIFICATION        | fm_price | fm_stock | vip_price | education_price | magento_id | omit | sku             | url                  | web_stock | magento_status_fm | magento_status_ff | ff_price_error | ff_stock_error |     fm_price_error | fm_stock_error | fm_vip_price_error | ff_vip_price_error | ff_check_date |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2017-12-12 12:53:01 | 2017-12-14 09:31:44 | 109      | NULL     | NULL      | NULL            | 15212      | NULL | epiea10nach1    | https://www.absolut… | NULL      | NULL              | 1                 | NULL           | NULL           | NULL               | NULL           | NULL               | NULL               | 2017-12-14    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2017-12-12 12:53:01 | 2017-12-14 09:31:44 | 545      | NULL     | NULL      | NULL            | 15433      | NULL | yamapx700mk2blk | https://www.absolut… | NULL      | NULL              | 1                 | NULL           | NULL           | NULL               | NULL           | NULL               | NULL               | 2017-12-14    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Prices:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| price_pk | CREATION            | MODIFICATION | entity_id_id | customer_group_id | final_price | min_price | check_date |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 260      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 0                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 261      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 1                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 262      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 2                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 263      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 3                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 264      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 4                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 265      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 5                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 266      | 2017-12-12 12:53:39 | NULL         | 15212        | 6                 | 109         | 109       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 988      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 0                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 989      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 1                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 990      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 2                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 991      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 3                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 992      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 4                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 993      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 5                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 994      | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15431        | 6                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1002     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 0                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1003     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 1                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1004     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 2                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1005     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 3                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1006     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 4                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1007     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 5                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1008     | 2017-12-12 12:53:42 | NULL         | 15433        | 6                 | 545         | 545       | NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are joined together on the Magento_Id (magento) field which is an integer.
The Product table has our correct price in
The Prices table has the magento prices on the site for different customer groups

There can be many prices per product, and I wish to check that the prices are correct against our internal db (so the website is correct)

I have written a SQL query that shows me where the price in the prices table does not equal the price in the Product table.

I have also got this working in PeeWee Orm.

I am struggling however, in getting peewee to show me the `final_price` from the Price table, even though my SQL query uses it as a comparator.

Example SQL:

```
 SELECT
 sku, magento_id, fm_price, price.final_price, `url`
 FROM
 products
 JOIN
 price
 ON
 `products`.`magento_id` = `price`.`entity_id_id` AND `price`.`customer_group_id` = 0
 WHERE
 `products`.`fm_price` != `price`.`final_price`
```

Example output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| sku            | magento_id | fm_price | final_price | url                                                  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bsrhtstudio20h | 17581      | 399      | 449         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rolac60rw      | 17697      | 479      | 475         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| yamthr5        | 17833      | 169.85   | 169         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rolgk3b        | 19636      | 155      | 152         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rolgk3         | 19763      | 155      | 152         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bosac3         | 20115      | 113      | 107.15      | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bosbd2         | 20128      | 79       | 77.95       | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bosch1         | 20140      | 77.5     | 71.92       | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And my Peewee query

```python
price_errors = Product.select(Product, Price.final_price).join(Price, on=(Product.magento == Price.entity_id) & (
            Price.customer_group_id == 0)).where(Product.fm_price != Price.final_price)
```

Which gives me the correct results, but I am unable to get access to the Price.final_price to display

I've tried the following:

for price_error in price_errors:
        print(price_error.price.final_price)

which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'price'
```

I have access to `price_set` but that shows all the items related via the foreign key join, not the join specified above

Ive added alias's to both the join and the select, but am still unable to get anything.

If I execute it with

```
price_errors = Product.raw("""SELECT id, sku, magento_id, fm_price, 
price.final_price, `url`
                                FROM products
                                JOIN price
                                ON `products`.`magento_id` = 
`price`.`entity_id_id` AND `price`.`customer_group_id` = 0
                                WHERE `products`.`fm_price` != 
`price`.`final_price`""")
```

Then I can access price_error.final_price

but this kind of defeats the use of the orm :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for product in price_errors:
     print product.price.final_price
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I meant to put down all the permutations I had tried, that being one of them, I'll update the question now

Comment: in your join on=expression, try adding an alias: .join((exp1... exp2).alias('price'))

Comment: price_errors = Product.select(Product, Price.final_price.alias('fprice')).join(Price, on=(Product.magento == Price.entity_id) & (
             Price.customer_group_id == 0)).alias('test_price').where(Product.fm_price != Price.final_price) - still unable to access via fprice, price, test_price etc :(